# Regression of outcome variable with sinusoidal periodicity?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, seasonality

In linear regression of an outcome variable with sinusoidal periodicity (eg seasonal temperature variation), is it sufficient to adjust for this variation by adding a cosine function [1] as a predictor?

I.e. Y= intercept + b*X + e, where Y has sinusoidal variation; adjust by Y = intercept + b1*X + b2*F(t) + e.

[1] A M Stolwijk. Studying seasonality by using sine and cosine functions in regression analysis. http://jech.bmj.com/content/53/4/235.full.pdf

Comment: It depends on what regressors you use.  If any linear combination of them exhibits periodicity of the same period, then you might not need any additional variables.  It is strange that you introduce a new variable "$t$" in a regression that does not involve $t$ at all: are you perhaps thinking of [tag:time-series]?

Comment: sorry, the cosine function is function of time, depending on when the assessment was performed